# Image not displaying in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, https, imageview

I am trying to display an image with "https" in the URL but I don't know why it is not showing up. (For example https://www.starkmedia.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/https.png). I have no idea what is going wrong as I don't get any exception either. Can someone help me figure out what is going wrong and how I can properly display the image?

I am new to Xcode and I am just trying to make some changes in the code written by some other developer.

```
- (void)downloadImageFromUrl:(NSString *)urlString
{
    NSLog(@"Url String: %@", urlString);
    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 179, 245)];
    NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];    

    self.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    self.imageView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    [self showImage];
}

- (void)showImage
{
    if ([self.scrollView.subviews count] == 3) {
        [self.imageView removeFromSuperview];
    }

    self.scrollView.alpha = 1;
    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:self.image];
    self.imageView.frame = (CGRect){.origin=CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f), .size=self.image.size};
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.imageView];

    // 2
    self.scrollView.contentSize = self.image.size;

    // 3
    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                   initWithTarget:self
                                                   action:@selector(scrollViewDoubleTapped:)];

    doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapRecognizer];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *twoFingerTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                      initWithTarget:self
                                                      action:@selector(scrollViewTwoFingerTapped:)];

    twoFingerTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    twoFingerTapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
    [self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:twoFingerTapRecognizer];

    // 4
    CGRect scrollViewFrame = self.scrollView.frame;
    CGFloat scaleWidth = scrollViewFrame.size.width / self.scrollView.contentSize.width;
    CGFloat scaleHeight = scrollViewFrame.size.height / self.scrollView.contentSize.height;
    CGFloat minScale = MIN(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minScale;

    // 5
    NSString *model = [[UIDevice currentDevice] model];

    if([model isEqualToString:@"iPad"]) {
        self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.5f;
    }

    else {
        self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.5f;
    }

    self.scrollView.zoomScale = minScale;

    // 6
    [self centerScrollViewContents];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is two way to do this Adding Manually or Using Pod

## Manually

[Download SDWebImage from Here](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

1.Add SDWebImage Folder to your Application.

[image]

2. And make sure that you are adding to all the targets that you want to use that library.

[image]

3.Now Import This in Your header file.

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
```

4.Use Below Code

```
 [self.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:"yoururl.png"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

5.Done.

## Using POD

This will help you to see whenever your dependencies get new updates. You'll also know which version are you using. This is a good practice.

1.You can eg use Cocoapods. Go to your Terminal, type:

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
```

2.Then go to your **project folder** (place, where you have xcodeproj) and type:

```
$ pod init
```

3.This creates a file named Podfile. Open it and paste:

```
platform :ios, '8.0' // or whatever you need
use_frameworks!

pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 3.7'
```

4.So when you have it ready, open Terminal and type:

```
$ pod install
```

5.From now you should work on xcworkspace instead od xcodeproj.

6.Now Import This in Your header file.

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
```

4.Use Below Code

```
 [self.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:"yoururl.png"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

5.Done.

Hope this helps.